# Кракозябры в начале строки в консоли

Tags: c++, mingw

Поставил кодировку utf-8:

```
SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
```

Вывожу текст в потоке:

```
cout << "Введите первое число: a = ";
```

А консоль выдает мне вот это:

```
��ведите первое число: a =
```

Пытался искать информацию в тырнете, ничего, к сожалению, не нашел, возможно неправильно искал. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Comment: @Abyx Версия `MinGW 3.21`, `CMake 3.5.1`, `GDB 7.8`; `Win 10`; `SetConsoleOutputCP` устанавливает кодировку вывода текста, без нее выходят кракозябры, кодировка исходников `utf-8`

Comment: Возможно, поможет fflush(stdout) / std::cout.flush()

Answer (score 3):

Это происходит из-за того, что низкоуровневые WinApi функции для вывода строк в консоль в UTF-8 ожидают завершенную строку. Такие функции как [puts](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/) выведут вашу строку корректно. А вот вывод через `basic_ostream<char>::operator<<(char*)` вероятно для строки

```
"Введите первое число: a = "
```

cначала вызывает winapi с первым байтом двухбайтового символа `В`, затем со вторым и остатком строки, что отображается как:

```
��ведите первое число: a =
```